# Complex conditional Regex grouping

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have the following text:

```
 1. The SBI considered this sub-item at its resumed 1^st^ meeting and at its 2^nd^ meeting (see
    para. 46 above). It had before it documents FCCC/CP/2011/7 and Corr.1 and Add.1 and 2, 
    FCCC/SBI/2010/17, FCCC/SBI/2010/26 and FCCC/SBI/2010/MISC.9. A statement was made on behalf of the LDCs.
```

I'm interested in extracting names of Documents that follow the pattern: `(FCCC\/(?:SBSTA|SBI|CP|KP\/CMP|PA\/CMA)\/[0-9]{4}\/(?:INF\.|L\.|MISC\.)?[0-9]+(?:\/Add\.[0-9])?(?:\/Rev\.[0-9]+)?)` this is, `FCCC/Document_type(SBSTA or SBI, etc.)/Year/Number` and they may or may not have adds, corrections and revisions.

There are two ways to refer to adds or revisions:

- Add them at the end of the name: adding /Rev or /Add + number
- or `and Rev|Add|Corr .num`

Then from the text I'm interested into build the names that are referenced with the second option.  For example, map: `FCCC/CP/2011/7 and Corr.1 and Add.1 and 2` to `["FCCC/CP/2011/7", "FCCC/CP/2011/7/Corr.1", "FCCC/CP/2011/7/Add.1", "FCCC/CP/2011/7/Add.2"]`.

This is my current approach:

```py
def _find_documents(par: str) -> Union[list, None]:
    """
    Finds referenced documents
    :param par:
    :return:
    """
    found_list = []
    pattern = r"(FCCC\/(?:SBSTA|SBI|CP|KP\/CMP|PA\/CMA)\/[0-9]{4}\/(?:INF\.|L\.|MISC\.)?[0-9]+(?:\/Add\.[0-9])?(?:\/Rev\.[0-9]+)?)"
    found = re.findall(pattern, par)

    # Now, we look for corrections and Revisions
    for doc in found:
        found_list.append(doc)
        doc = doc.replace(r"/", r"\/")
        pattern = doc + r"(?: and ((:?Corr\.|Add\.)?[0-9]))?(?: and ((:?Corr\.|Add\.)[0-9]))*(:? and ([0-9])+)?"
        res = re.search(pattern, par).groups()
        for pat in res:
            if pat is not None:
                found_list.append(doc + "/" + pat)

    return found_list if found_list is not None else None

    st = r"""
    50. The SBI considered this sub-item at its resumed 1^st^ meeting and at its 2^nd^ meeting (see para. 46 above). It had before it documents FCCC/CP/2011/7 and Corr.1 and Add.1 and 2, FCCC/SBI/2010/17, FCCC/SBI/2010/26 and FCCC/SBI/2010/MISC.9. A statement was made on behalf of the LDCs.
    """
    
    _find_documents(st)
    """ [OUT]: 
    ['FCCC/CP/2011/7',
     'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/Corr.1',
    'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/Corr.',  EXTRA
    'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/Add.1',
    'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/Add.',  EXTRA
    'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/ and 2',  EXTRA
    'FCCC\\/CP\\/2011\\/7/2', WRONG Should be FCCC/CP/2011/7/Add.2
    'FCCC/SBI/2010/17',
    'FCCC/SBI/2010/26',
    'FCCC/SBI/2010/MISC.9']"""
```

As you can see I have several problems that I don't know how to solve.

1. The group capture extra matches `["Add.", "Corr.", "and 2"]`
2. When I try to append Corrs, Apps, the `/` is somehow escaped.
3. Not sure how to map submatch `and 2` into `/Add.2` or `/Corr.2` depending on the previous

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Note: The forward slash `/` has no meaning in regex, you don't need to escape it. This also means `doc.replace(r"/", r"\/")` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: As to problem 1:  You have mis-typed the non-capturing group operator "(?:" as "(:?" in a couple of places.  Fixing that will resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "50. The SBI considered this sub-item at its resumed 1^st^ meeting and at its 2^nd^ meeting (see para. 46 above). It had before it documents FCCC/CP/2011/7 and Corr.1 and Add.1 and 2, FCCC/SBI/2010/17, FCCC/SBI/2010/26 and FCCC/SBI/2010/MISC.9. A statement was made on behalf of the LDCs."
rx_main = re.compile(r'(FCCC/(?:SBSTA|SBI|CP|KP/CMP|PA/CMA)/\d{4}/(?:INF\.|L\.|MISC\.)?\d+)((?:(?:/|\s+and\s+|\s*,\s*)(?:Add|Rev|Corr)\.\d+(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+)\d+)*)*)')
rx_rev = re.compile(r'(?:Add|Rev|Corr)\.\d+(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+)\d+)*')
rx_split = re.compile(r'\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+')
matches = rx_main.finditer(text)
results = []
for m in matches:
    results.append(m.group(1))
    chunks = [rx_split.split(x) for x in rx_rev.findall(m.group(2))]
    for ch in chunks:
        if len(ch) == 1: # it is simple, just add first item to Group 1
            results.append(f"{m.group(1)}/{ch[0]}")
        else:
            name = ch[0].split('.')[0] # Rev, Corr or Add
            for c in ch:
                if '.' in c: # if there is a dot, append whole string to Group 1
                    results.append(f"{m.group(1)}/{c}")
                else:
                    results.append(f"{m.group(1)}/{name}.{c}") # Append the new number to Corr/Add/Rev

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['FCCC/CP/2011/7', 'FCCC/CP/2011/7/Corr.1', 'FCCC/CP/2011/7/Add.1', 'FCCC/CP/2011/7/Add.2', 'FCCC/SBI/2010/17', 'FCCC/SBI/2010/26', 'FCCC/SBI/2010/MISC.9']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/GWwshL).

The new regex is

```
(FCCC/(?:SBSTA|SBI|CP|KP/CMP|PA/CMA)/\d{4}/(?:INF\.|L\.|MISC\.)?\d+)((?:(?:/|\s+and\s+|\s*,\s*)(?:Add|Rev|Corr)\.\d+(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+)\d+)*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MKbHTj/1).